# How to pass information between beans in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a scenario and dont have a clear idea for this to work yet.

Here's the example scenario :

1. I have a ***myView.xhtml*** file that can be displayed as a window popup or a primefaces dialog popup from ***2 other container xhtml***, let's say ***container1.xhtml*** and ***container2.xhtml*** (the ***myView.xhtml*** is included with something like this ? `<ui:include src="myView.xhtml" />`)
2. And, we also have the view-scoped beans, let's call them ***myViewBean***, ***container1Bean*** and ***container2Bean***
3. ***container1Bean*** has the property of ***transactionDate***, and ***container2Bean*** has a property of ***transDate***
4. ***myViewBean***'s @PostConstruct method will query the database ***based on a parameter of type date***.
5. On container1.xhtml, if a user clicks on a button that will popup the ***myView.xhtml***, ***container1Bean*** should be able to provide it's ***transactionDate*** to the ***myViewBean***, and ***myViewBean*** will be able to query based on it in the @PostConstruct method.
6. On container2.xhtml, if a user clicks on a button that will popup the ***myView.xhtml***, ***container2Bean*** should be able to provide it's ***transDate*** to the ***myViewBean***, and ***myViewBean*** will be able to query based on it in the @PostConstruct method.

I was thinking about using ***@Inject Container1Bean*** and ***@Inject Container2Bean*** in the ***MyViewBean***, so that inside ***MyViewBean***, i can get the ***transactionDate of container1Bean*** or ***transDate of container2Bean***. To decide which container bean is active is to check which one is not null.

But what if the container beans grows, there could be other container beans that make use of the MyViewBean, and the ***@Inject ContainerXXBean*** will grow in numbers inside the ***MyViewBean***. There must be other solutions for this.

Please share ideas on how to accomplish this .. Thank you ! :-)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If container1Bean, myViewBean and container2Bean share some properties, why not putting them in a new bean ? (let's call it sharedBean, but I'm sure you'll find a better name adapted to your case). You could then inject sharedBean using @ManagedProperty in every dependent bean. Let's just try not to have circular references.

I'll also suggest to review your architecture. Are you sure you need all thoses beans, partitionned exactly like this? This sounds like something which will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. And im very very interested in your suggestion on reviewing the architecture. I have a basic thinking that every page will have it's own view-scoped-bean to handle each page's action. And also, some pages are reusable and can be viewed from other pages, and can be parameterized (just like the example, that viewBean can have different query results based on the params). Do you have any suggestions on how to partition the jsf beans ? I've been wondering also about the best practice for this. Thanks !

Comment: I'd just say, make a small diagram on paper. You could share a bean for multiple views, it helps sometimes. Also, if multiple views on your diagram share too much info, just make them share the bean. For the rest, just ask yourself whether you should have views with parameters (should it be possible to have an influence on the view by changing the url?) or if you should just call methods (with parameters, which could be objects) to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access only the contents of the other beans you can do that programmatic.

Get the current instance of the FacesContext inside from one bean. And using that context you can grab the instance of other beans.

See this [illustration](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/access-a-managed-bean-from-event-listener-jsf/). As per the title of your question, you want to some information between beans. You can accomplish this by calling the other bean's public methods, which may be specifically created for this purpose. (setters-getters).

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a list of ways to get a bean form the FacesContext. But i think my situation here is not about the fetching the bean by name, since i could do with the @Inject. It's more to the how can i make a reusable view/bean that can somehow be parameterized from  another containing view. Im begininning to think about using a JSF 2 composite component for this. hehe ..